# SwiftUI: How to make a list that ignores the max of HStacks

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to create a list like this
But as soon as I add more then 10 elements I get the error
"Extra argument in call"
I know this error happens because I have to many Stacks in my View

[image: list Image]

What would the best way be to build a list like this that is scrollable and I can add Views With different values that are stylized?

my code so far

```
List{
            CardView()
            CardView()
            CardView()
            CardView()
            CardView()
        }
```

and the CardView is

```
struct CardView: View {
var body: some View {
    HStack{
        Image(systemName: "circle.hexagongrid")
        Divider()
        Text("Text")
            .frame(minWidth: 100)
        Divider()
        Spacer()
        Text("1111")
    }
}
```

}

is there a better option in SwiftUI to display lists like this?
I would also like to have a bit of space between the CardView's but I can figure that out later when I know how to build my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `ForEach`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<30) { item in
                CardView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

30 is the number of views that will get created

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was something easy I overlooked.